# authorization code from Azure AD OAuth2AuthorizationResponse

Tags: azure, spring-boot

I have got the Springboot Active Directory example up and running as specified here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/master/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-active-directory-spring-boot-backend-sample

I can log in with my Azure AD credentials, using a Client ID that I created and granted 'Windows Azure Active Directory' permissions on.

Next step is I'd like to get the logged-in user's profile picture, so I need to get the Authorization Code from the `OAuth2AuthorizationResponse`

It's not clear to me how to access this data.  It's not available in the returned OAuth2User object

I tried setting up a HandlerInterceptor on /login/oauth2/code/azure so I can intercept the Response, but this never gets hit (?)

I also tried adding a custom filter:

```
http.addFilterAfter(
              new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

but this never gets hit for the `/login/oauth2/code/azure` URI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to intercept the Authentication response by overriding `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and adding it to my security config:

```
http....
 .and().oauth2Login().successHandler(authCodeCachingSuccessHandler)
```

where I cache the code and pass to superclass to handle:

```
 @Override
 public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
    String[] s = parameterMap.get("code");
    tokenCache.setAuthCode( (DefaultOidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal(), s[0] );

    super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
 }
```

I doubt this is 'best practice' but it does work, and I've yet to find a more elegant way